# C++ Assign Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fn(int* input_ptr) {
    int *ptr2 = input_ptr;
    cout << "pointer 2 is " << *ptr2 << endl;
}

int main() {
    int *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = 7;
    fn(ptr1);
}
```

This example works, as I pass a pointer to the function, and assign that to a temporary pointer inside the function, the result shows pointer 2 is also 7.
However,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = 7;
    int *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = ptr1; // or I have also tried *ptr2 = *ptr1
    cout << "pointer 2 is " << *ptr2 << endl;
}
```

The same step does not work in the main function. I know you can use the address ptr2 = ptr1 without asterisk and it will work.

However, in the first example, I can directly assign a pointer as a function parameter to a new pointer with asterisk (or called dereferecing?), but in the second example I cannot do that in main function.

Could anyone help with this question? Appreciate your time.

Comment: `This example works,` - You are just lucky. `ptr1` is not given memory address to point to. You need to use `new` to allocate memory

Answer (score 10):

In both examples, you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which is *undefined behaviour*.

For the pointer assignment question, you can directly assign:

```
 int *ptr2 = ptr2;
```

in your second example, provided you make sure `ptr1` points at a valid location. For example,

```
int x;
int *ptr1 = &x; /* ptr1 now points to the address of x */
*ptr1 = 7;
int *ptr2;
ptr1 = ptr2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I have one more question, `int *ptr1 = &x;` is equal to `int *ptr1;   ptr1 = &x;` right?

Answer (score 5):

In `main`, variable `ptr1` is not initialized to point to a properly allocated block of memory.

Hence the rest of your program yields undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There's a major problem with how you are using pointers here. Directly dereferencing a pointer can cause undefined behavior as suggested by usr and barak

You need to allocate memory for the pointer here using

```
int* ptr1 = new int[1];
```

Also since you're the one allocating memory, you need to clean up before exiting with

```
delete[] ptr1;
```

In case you don't wish to work with Dynamic Memory allocation, you could initialize it as

```
int a = 7;
int* ptr1 = &a;
```

This way you won't be dereferencing stray pointers and causing undefined behavior.

Regarding your output with

```
 *ptr1 = ptr2; // or I have also tried *ptr1 = *ptr2
```

Assignment of values in C++ or C is from right to left. Hence ptr2 won't have the values of ptr1;

For example;

```
int a  = 5;
int b = 6;

a=b;
```

would make `a = 6`.

Conversely

```
b = a;
```

would make `b = 5`.

Comment: Instead of `int* ptr1 = new int[1];` you could use `new int`